# Assigning variables inside a function: Strange behaviour

Tags: python

I use Python rarely, so it's unclear to me why such behaviour is allowed:
There is no w object and hence it has no s attribute, then why f allows to make `w.s` assignment?

```
>>> def f():
    w.s="ads"  #allows, no exception
>>> w.s="sds"  #outside function
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<pyshell#74>", line 1, in <module>
    w.s="sds"
NameError: name 'w' is not defined
```

Comment: Once you call `f()` it will show the same error. Until or unless you have not called it, it will not show any error.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Such behaviour is allowed because Python is a dynamic language. At compilation time, when the `f` function definition is executed (i.e., compiled to byte code), the interpreter knows that there in no local object in the function bound to the name `w`, so `w` must refer to a global object. Sure, there is *currently* no object in the global scope which is bound to that name, but that doesn't matter: Python assumes you know what you're doing, until proven otherwise :).

We can use the [`dis`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/dis.html) module to disassemble the function's byte code. Here's a short demo.

```
from dis import dis

def f():
    w.s = "ads"

dis(f)
print('- ' * 30)

class Test(object):
    pass

try:
    f()
except Exception as e:
    print(e)

w = Test()
f()
print(w.__dict__)
```

**output**

```
 40           0 LOAD_CONST               1 ('ads')
              3 LOAD_GLOBAL              0 (w)
              6 STORE_ATTR               1 (s)
              9 LOAD_CONST               0 (None)
             12 RETURN_VALUE
- - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - 
name 'w' is not defined
{'s': 'ads'}
```

FWIW, in Python 2 the byte code for `f` is identical, but the `NameException` error message is
`global name 'w' is not defined`.

So if we try to call `f()` without a valid `w` in the global scope at the time of the call we will get an exception, but if there _is _ a valid `w` then everything's ok.

Note that `w` *must* be in the global scope, a local `w` inside another function will not work. Eg:

```
def f():
    w.s = "ads"

class Test(object):
    pass

def g():
    w = Test()
    try:
        f()
    except Exception as e:
        print(e)
    print(w.__dict__)

g()
```

**output**

```
name 'w' is not defined
{}
```

Answer (score 5):

Try running your function and see what happens. Python doesn't catch it as you write your code but as soon as you run the code it will error.

What you see is because python doesn't know that by the time your function runs there won't be an object `w` with an attribute `s`. However, when you do it outside the function call it checks that there is no `w` in the scope and thus errors.

Try this:

```
def f():
    w.s = "one"
w.s  = "one" # called before there is such an object
f() # called before w exists, it will error out    

class SomeClass(object):
    def __init__(self):
        self.s = "two"

w = SomeClass()
f() # since w exists it will run
```

Comment: Sorry I posted my answer in a hurry, realized it after clearing looking at it "NameError". Thank you

Answer (score 4):

A function is not yet being run because it hasn't been called yet, as opposed to the assignment of `w.s` to `"sds"` being done outside of the function.